# eslint show error on undefined in typescript code

Tags: typescript, eslint

[image]

I have a typescript project, I use `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` to lint it.

It seems `eslint` couldn't recognize `undefined` in my project. The error message is:

```
Variable 'undefined' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7005)
```

I have searched on the internet but got nothing.

Have you ever got the same problem?

Comment: I've already found the solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to add the line below to `tsconfig.ts`?:

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to resolve it:

1. `npm i @types/node --save-dev`
2. `"lib": ["esnext", "DOM"]` in tsconfig.json

You don't need to do both of them.